# How to process input data from a text file

Tags: python, file, input, text

I am beginner in Python. In order to practice it I do exercises from Code Abbey. They often present their input data as columns of numbers. In the below example I was supposed to calculate the sum of first members of arithmetic sequence. The input data was presented in three columns:

25 12 77

27 14 95

8 0 30

…

where the number in the first column was a starting point of a sequence, the number in the second column was the increment value, and the number in last column showed the number of values that were supposed to be summed up.

As these lists with input data are often quite lengthy, I do not want to have them hardcoded inside the script. So I copied, pasted and saved them in a plain text file.
Before I could proceed with the exercise itself I had to go through four “for” loops to convert initial text file into workable format (going from strings into integers). Besides, I had to create several list into which I appended subsequent results.

After the first “for” loop I got a list of strings: ['25 12 77’, ’27 14 95’,….]

After the second “for” loop I got a list of lists of strings [['25', '12', '77'], ['27', '14', '95']…]

After the third and fourth (nested) “for” loop I finally received a list of integers [25, 12, 77, 27, 14, 95…]

```python
with open("input_progression.txt") as file:

    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        lines.append(line)

    for strings in lines:
        strings = strings.split(' ')
        g.append(strings)

    for sublist in g:
       for item in sublist:
           flat_list.append(item)
        flat_list = list(map(int, flat_list))

    for numbers in range(int(len(flat_list) / 3)):
        for integer in range(0, flat_list[counter + 2]):
            result += (flat_list[counter] + flat_list[counter + 1] * integer)
        outcome.append(result)
        counter += 3
        result = 0
print (outcome)
```

It was quite tedious job (all these thing were new to me). Do you know any simpler (or perhaps Pythonian) way how to do it? Is there somewhere a tutorial how to use text files as input?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
with open("input_progression.txt") as f:
    outcome = [int(item) for sublist in [l.split() for l in f] for item in sublist]
print(outcome)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the result I receive using  your code is a list of strings and not integers. Something like: ['14', '9', '50', '30', ....]

Comment: Wow, it works as expected now. One line of code instead of ten. A bit advanced but I will use your code even if I do not completely understand it (yet). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is more shorter and precise

```
flat_list = []
outcome = []
counter = 0
result = 0
with open("input_progression.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    if len(line) >= 1: flat_list.append(line) 
flat_list = [int(item) for sublist in flat_list for item in sublist]


for numbers in range(int(len(flat_list) / 3)):
    for integer in range(0, flat_list[counter + 2]):
        result += (flat_list[counter] + flat_list[counter + 1] * integer)
    outcome.append(result)
    counter += 3
    result = 0
print (outcome)
```

Comment: Hi, when I print your flat_list I receive only the last three digits [8, 0, 30]. I would expect to have the whole list [25, 12, 77, 27, 14, 95, 8, 0, 30]

Answer (score 0):

You could use fewer loops.

```
with open("input_progression.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(" ")
        start = int(line[0])
        incr_val = int(line[1])
        num_loops = int(line[2])
        for n in range(num_loops):
            start += incr_val #Increment
        print(start) #answer for each row
```

Comment: Hi, the results are unexpected. With the numbers I gave as an example (25 12 77, etc.) I receive the output: 949, 1357, 8.

Comment: Maybe I read your question wrong. I understood for each row column 1 =  start value, column 2 =  increment value and column3 is the number of times to increment. Is this not correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But with the input [25, 12, 77, 27, 14, 95, 8, 0, 30] the expected result is [37037, 65075, 240]. But somehow, when using your code I receive [949, 1357, 8]. However, it's not the point. The problem is how to convert a txt file with three columns of string into a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for parsing text files with greater ease.

```
import re
file = open("input_progression.txt", "r")
text = ""
for line in file:
  text = text + line
outcome = [int(num) for num in re.findall("[0-9]+", text)]
print(outcome)
```